# not able to close the jquery iframe thickbox when the page is https

Tags: javascript, jquery, thickbox

I have jQuery `thickbox(TB_iframe=true)` which shows an https page in an iframe based overlay.

the parent page is http & overlay page is https. if i use

```
self.parent.tb_remove()
```

This does not work and gives me

Permission denied for `<https://www.abc.com>` to get property `Window.tb_remove` from `<http://www.abc.com>`.

Any solution. I want to be able to close the thikbox irrespective to whether its is https or http page that it is displaying in an iframe.

Comment: is the page you are displaying in the iframe in the same domain as the page you opened the thickbox lightframe?

Comment: yes ,its the same domain.But as http and https run on different ports it take it as different domains.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a iFrame to communicate. However, you will want it to be locked down very hard to prevent XSS.

Create a second page, say http://www.abc.com/thickboxClose. That page, contains javascript that closes the thickbox. E.g., window.parent.parent.tb_remove().

Then to close your iframe, you create a hidden iFrame pointing to that page. Since it is on the same domain, it can reach through to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

use a relational url like ../page.html instead of http://domain.com/page.htm as your link. check that the page opening the thickbox lightframe is in the same domain as the page being displayed in the light frame.

i wrote a javascript function to create and open a light frame similar to thickbox, maybe it will help
[jLightFrame](http://codemonkey.za.net/Projects/jLightFrame/jLightFrame.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel said, you should use a relative url. The reason it fails is because you you must only read javascript content at the same "trust" (ssl) level that you are currently on.

You wouldn't want your bank's HTTPS site doing an ajax query to a non-https web service would you?

Answer (score -2):

Try this

From the iframe

```
<a href="http://www.abc.com" target="_parent">Close</a>
```

Attempting this with any sort of javsacript is just going to be a hack